# Using DaprServer to expose endpoints from NestJs Webapp

Tags: express, nestjs, dapr

`DaprServer` allows to [expose http api endpoints defined in an `express` middleware instance.](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/sdks/js/js-server/#using-http-bring-your-own-express-webserver)

In a NestJs app, it is possible to [get the application's internal `express` middleware instance](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter) and pass it to the DaprServer instance:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DaprServer } from '@dapr/dapr';
import type { Express } from 'express';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const middleware: Express = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  const daprServer = new DaprServer({
    serverHost: '127.0.0.1',
    serverPort: '3000',
    serverHttp: middleware,
  });

  await daprServer.start();
  // NestJs app.listen call is removed
  // await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

The DaprServer instance is started and the call to `app.listen` is removed, **however endpoints defined in controllers are not available.**

Is it possible to use DaprServer with NestJs in this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NestJs `app` instance was missing an initialization:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DaprServer } from '@dapr/dapr';
import type { Express } from 'express';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // Initialize the Nest app instance
  const initedApp = await app.init();

  const middleware: Express = initedApp.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  const daprServer = new DaprServer({
    serverHost: '127.0.0.1',
    serverPort: '3000',
    serverHttp: middleware,
  });

  await daprServer.start();
  // NestJs app.listen call is removed
  // await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

It seems that `app.listen` calls `app.init` internally , now that we don't rely on `app.listen` we have to call `app.init` directly before getting the `express` middleware.